# Load ng2-table data form API

Tags: typescript, angular

I am learning Angular 2, and I want to fill a ng2-table using an API data in PHP, I have a service that returns the data, but I don't know how to fill the data variable with the subscribe data of the service. I am calling the service method getLanguages().

my service code is :

```
import { Injectable,bind}    from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Language} from './language';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {
    private languagesUrl =   '../languages/get_all_languages';  // URL to webapi
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getLanguages(): Observable<Language[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.languagesUrl)
            .map((responseData) => {

                return responseData.json();
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getAllLanguages(){
       return this.http.get(this.languagesUrl).map(res => res.json());
   }

    private handleError (error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

}
```

My component code is :

```
import { Component,OnInit}      from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf} from '@angular/common'
import { Language }             from './language';
import { LanguageService }      from './language.service';
import {PAGINATION_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {NG_TABLE_DIRECTIVES}    from 'ng2-table/ng2-table'
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {TableData} from './table-data';
@Component({
    selector: 'languages_list',
    templateUrl: '../app/core/Languages/language-list.component.html',
    styleUrls:  ['../app/core/Languages/language.component.css'],
    directives: [NG_TABLE_DIRECTIVES, PAGINATION_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgIf, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]

})

export class LanguageComponent implements OnInit {

  languages: Language[];
  errorMessage: string;
  mode = 'Observable';  
  public rows:Array<any> = [];
  public columns:Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Code', name: 'code',sort: 'asc'},
    {title: 'Name', name: 'name', sort: 'asc'}
  ];
  public page:number = 1;
  public itemsPerPage:number = 10;
  public maxSize:number = 5;
  public numPages:number = 1;
  public length:number = 0;


  public config:any = {
    paging: true,
    sorting: {columns: this.columns},
    filtering: {filterString: '', columnName: 'name'}
  };


  public data: Array<any> =[];


  public constructor(private _languageService: LanguageService) {

     this._languageService.getLanguages()
         .subscribe(
            languages =>this.languages =languages,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
         )

    this.length = this.data.length;
     //this.data =[{"code":"en","name":"English"},{"code":"es","name":"Spanish"}];
    //this.data =this.getLanguages();


        // this.data =[{"code":"en","name":"English"},{"code":"es","name":"Spanish"}];


  }

  public ngOnInit():void {
    this.onChangeTable(this.config);
   // this.getLanguages();
  }

  public changePage(page:any, data:Array<any> = this.data):Array<any> {

    let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
    let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : data.length;
    return data.slice(start, end);
  }

  public changeSort(data:any, config:any):any {
    if (!config.sorting) {
      return data;
    }

    let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
    let columnName:string = void 0;
    let sort:string = void 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      if (columns[i].sort !== '') {
        columnName = columns[i].name;
        sort = columns[i].sort;
      }
    }

    if (!columnName) {
      return data;
    }

    // simple sorting
    return data.sort((previous:any, current:any) => {
      if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }

  public changeFilter(data:any, config:any):any {
    if (!config.filtering) {
      return data;
    }

    let filteredData:Array<any> = data.filter((item:any) =>
      item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));

    return filteredData;
  }

  public onChangeTable(config:any, page:any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}):any {
    if (config.filtering) {
      Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
    }
    if (config.sorting) {
      Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
    }

    let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
    let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
    this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
    this.length = sortedData.length;
  }

  public getLanguages() {
       return this._languageService
            .getLanguages()
            .subscribe(
                languages => this.languages= languages,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }


}
```

I already test the services and is returning data, How I fill the variable this.data in the constructor with the data result of the service that I have in my function?

```
 public getLanguages() {
       return this._languageService
            .getLanguages()
            .subscribe(
                languages => this.languages= languages,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve the problem calling the service in the onChangeTable and loading the data in the subscribe method.

```
 public onChangeTable(config:any, page:any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}):any {
    if (config.filtering) {
      Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
    }
    if (config.sorting) {
      Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
    }

       this._languageService.getLanguages()
         .subscribe(languages => {
            this.data =languages;
            this.length = this.data.length;
            let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
            let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
            this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
            this.length = sortedData.length;
        },error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)
  }
```