# How to Assign subscribe data in Angular 2 constructor?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am learning Angular 2 , I need to assign the result of my service to the data variable in the constructor of my component.
How can I use the subscribe data in the constructor and assign this values to my public data array?

```
public data: Array<any> =[];

public constructor(private _languageService: LanguageService){

    this._languageService.getLanguages()
    .subscribe(languages => {this.languages =languages;}
        ,error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)

    this.length = this.data.length;
    //How i can set  this.data = this.languages  
    //if  this.languages is empty outside the subscribe?
}
```

I really appreciate if someone can explain to me how to assign the data returned by the service to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to assign all the values inside of the `.subscribe()`

```
public data: Array<any> =[];

public constructor(private _languageService: LanguageService){

    this._languageService
        .getLanguages()
        .subscribe(languages => {
            this.languages =languages;
            [].push.apply(this.data, languages);
        },error => this.errorMessage = <any>error)

    ...
}
```

The construct `[].push.apply(target, source)` will push all coming values to existing array reference

EXTEND

We can load the data via *observable* source and consume then once they are available. We use `*ngIf` in template

```
<div>
   <some-component
      *ngIf="myData"
       [bindSource]="myData"
       ...
   ></some-component>
</div>
```

And in component we can subscribe to get that data:

```
public myData: any[] =[];

public constructor(private _languageService: LanguageService){

    this._languageService
        .getLanguages()
        .subscribe(languages => {
            this.myData = languages;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you  , i already try this, but the value of the data array is still empty in the constructor if  i do a console.log(this.data) outside the subscribe. that why my ng2-table does not load the data. i have more code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844511/load-ng2-table-data-form-api

Comment: Well.. that is ... logical. Constructor is a place, where you subscribe. And that's it.. code leaves it and continues in execution elsewhere.. Later, once the observer (you've subscribed to) will emit value.. the .subscribe is triggered. So.. there is NO way how to consume the value.. coming in the future.. directly in the constructor. that's why we subscribe... does it help a bit?

Comment: thank you, but now i do not understand how i can get data from my service and load the data  in the array to fill the ng2-table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844511/load-ng2-table-data-form-api ,there is another way to fill that array in the cosntructor from a service?

Comment: That is not how the angular2 works. Simply, firstly load your data (async) ... and get them with subscribe.. then pass them to any other component, I will extend my answer with a small hint

Comment: I extended the answer with one example how to get async data and pass them to another component. Hope it will get you closer